# UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint on Sql Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi guys I have to update a foreign key, on a server sql 2014, but when I run the code below I have the following error, how can fix it?

**Error:**

*Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0.
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_restirizione_idrapportomobile". The conflict occurred in database "db", table "dbo.RapportoMobile", column 'IdRapportoMobile'. (Line 1)*

**SQL Code:**

```
UPDATE risorsarapportomobile 
SET    risorsarapportomobile.idrapportomobile = 1236 
WHERE  risorsarapportomobile.idrisorseumane IN (SELECT 
       risorseumane.idrisorseumane 
                                                FROM   risorsarapportomobile 
                                                       INNER JOIN risorseumane 
                                                               ON 
       risorseumane.idrisorseumane = 
       risorsarapportomobile.idrisorseumane 
       WHERE  risorsarapportomobile.idrapportomobile IS NULL 
       AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '26-06-2018', 105) = 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), risorseumane.data, 105) 
       AND risorseumane.idcantiere = 158)
```

**Tables:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: value 1236 has to already be in whatever table the foreign key points at. If you extract the foreign key definition it will tell you what that table is. Foreign Keys are pretty fundamental concepts in database - you should understand them

Comment: The FK is there for a reason - don't drop it!

Comment: You are trying to update a key in a table which references the table `RapportoMobile`. This would mean your keys wouldn't match. If you have a ON UPDATE CASCADE constraint on `RapportoMobile` then updating the primary table would fix it. But it has to be done here first

Comment: We'll need your FK's code. Can you find this FK (On SSMS Object Explorer,expand (+ icon) risorsarapportomobile, expand Keyes, right click on "fk_restirizione_idrapportomobile", Modify) and post its code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `idRaprortoMobile` is `12`, not `1236`. `1236` is `idRapporto`. Check what column your foreign key points to, and you'll see it's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one field after SET, and due to the error message, we can deduce that

> the value 1236 you want to enter is not present in dbo.RapportoMobile.IdRapportoMobile, which is the target of the foreign key.

Add the value to that column first, then run your update.

Comment: and how do I know which rows to update without first selecting?

Comment: Not sure what sequence you mean. You have to INSERT INTO dbo.RapportoMobile a row with IdRapportoMobile=1236, and AFTERWARDS you can do your UPDATE.

Comment: the value 1236 is already present in table RapportoMobile, I just have to update another table with that value

Comment: 1236 must be in column  IdRapportoMobile, NOT RapportoMobile

Comment: If idrapportomobile should target RapportoMobile instead of IdRapportoMobile, then your trigger is wrong. Else, maybe you should use 12 instead of 1236 since this is the corresponding value to the row you are mentioning.